# Windows says not found pip3 for python but is install and work correctly?

Tags: python, cmd, pip

I installed Python and I am using it in VS Code, but, when I install libraries in Terminal via `pip3`, I get an error telling me that `pip3` is not a command.

I also checked for my version of Python and I get this other error:

[image: The Error of CMD that show command not found]

What should I do to fix this?
My python is `3.8.3` for `Amd64` and it is installed in under `D:\Python\Python38\python.exe`.

Comment: add Pip/python to path I think

Comment: Try `python --version` (and plain `pip` to do the install).

Comment: i test it not work !!

Comment: try:  pip install ...

Comment: @dimay its not work i test it now

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+is+not+recognized+as+an+internal+or+external+command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as A.H. says I search for how add **Paython** in **path** and I found it in https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/
just i need to know what is problem and it is name is python Path in **Environment Variables**
I Add path of the ***python.exe*** to my system **Environment Variables** ( I add this *Address* as you can see **;D:\Python\Python34** and dont forget to write **semicolon** character **;** before the Address)
[full method of do it in 1 picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk2SW.jpg)

I recommend to see top site if have problem to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the path to the Environment Variables. Under win10, You can find here:
Control Panel\System and Security\System. You will find there the Environment Variables. In there choose the Path and Edit it. Add your python with its path there, and then 'ok' everything.

Comment: i find it here and what am i must do now see it : https://ibb.co/xsWQjST